# Bottle - redirect after processing POST data

Tags: python-3.x, wsgi, bottle

I'm using bottle to build a tiny web app. I have a simple login form. I want to stay on the login form if the authentication is not successful, otherwise navigate to the main page.
However, in the function that processes the login form's POST, it looks like it just ignores the redirect:

```py
@route('/')
@view('login.html')
def promotool():
    return {'error': 'none'}

@route('/login', method="POST")
@view('login.html')
def login():
    try:
        if auth_success:
            bottle.redirect('/main_app')
        return {'error': 'LoginError'}
    except:
        return {'error': 'LoginError'}
```

After this, in the server log I only see the POST, but not the redirect:

```
"POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 4032
```

If I target my form on login.html to /main_app as the POST target, then I'm back to square one, because in that case I'd need to redirect to "/" to do the login in case of authentication error.

How do I make the redirect work or otherwise code this?

Comment: Is there more code than this? Specifically: where is `auth_success` defined? Because as written, this code will always return HTTP 200 due to a `NameError`.

Comment: Suggestion: on error, return an error code, not 200. On auth error, return 401; on other error, return 500. Then you'll know which path your code is taking. Also: include some context in the error response (e.g. `str(exc)`, where `exc` is the exception you caught).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I missed a key information from the documentation.
The wat the redirect method works is that it raises a HTTPResponse as an exception, and my generic exception handler caught that. So I resolved it by adding this to my code:

```py
except bottle.HTTPResponse:
        raise
```